# Chrome javascript error: Refused to get unsafe header X-Response-Time with servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I am getting this error in the chrome console.

I added the X-Response-Time header to allowedHeaders to the CorsFeatures

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
"*",
allowCredentials: true,
allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, X-Response-Time"));
```

I added the header to the response too, any idea?

```
[AddHeader(name: "X-Response-Time",value: "")]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I added the header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` and works!

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, X-Response-Time
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, X-Response-Time
```